# Confidence interval from binomial distribution: different results using `qbinom` and `binom.test`

Tags: r, binomial-cdf

I expect identical results calculating a CI for a proportion using `qbinom` and `binom.test`, but they are actually slightly different:

```
success <- 360
n <- 1226
lci <- qbinom(0.025, n, success/n)/n
uci <- qbinom(0.975, n, success/n)/n
c(lci, uci)

[1] 0.2683524 0.3189233

binom.test(success, n, success/n)$conf.int

[1] 0.2682571 0.3200123
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Looking at the source for `bins.test` the confidence limits are calculated using the `qbeta()`function.  Upper limit is `qbeta(1 - alpha, x + 1, n - x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code for the `binom.test` function uses `qbeta` rather than `qbinom`, as this is the accepted formula for [exact binomial confidence intervals](https://sigmazone.com/binomial-confidence-intervals/). Where `x` is the number of successes, the lci and uci as given by `binom.test` are:

```
p.L <- function(x, alpha) {
    if (x == 0) 
        0
    else qbeta(alpha, x, n - x + 1)
}
p.U <- function(x, alpha) {
    if (x == n) 
        1
    else qbeta(1 - alpha, x + 1, n - x)
}

alpha <- (1 - 0.95)/2
lci <- p.L(x, alpha)
uci <- p.U(x, alpha)
```